# KSQL JOIN to return only one result with duplicated Keys

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have some KSQL queries running on top of Kafka (currenlty in version 5.52, planning to upgrade to lastest soon).

Imagine you have 2 streams stream_A, stream_B, but you may have some duplicated id's in stream_B.id (for example some retries the applications has logged).

When you do something like:

```sql
CREATE STREAM result WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC="some_topic") AS
SELECT stream_A.field, stream_B.field
FROM stream_A INNER JOIN stream_B on steam_A.id = stream_B.id;
```

Is there a way to tell KSQL that you only want to get the first one of those matches?